# AS3 - How can I find the total time of an mp3 before is downloaded?

Tags: flash, audio, mp3

How can I find the total time of an mp3 before it is fully downloaded? I have this function which is called on TimerEvent.TIMER

```
private function onTick(e:TimerEvent):void
 {
  _soundLength = _sound.length;
  _position = _channel.position;
  mp3Interface.timeBar.timers.elapsedTime.text = ascb.util.DateFormat.formatMilliseconds(_position);
  mp3Interface.timeBar.timers.totalTime.text = ascb.util.DateFormat.formatMilliseconds(_soundLength);
  var percentPlayed:Number = Math.round((_position/_soundLength)*100);
  mp3Interface.timeBar.seeker.x = (percentPlayed*mp3Interface.timeBar.progressBar.width-5)/100;
 }
```

The problem is tha the totalTime is correct only when the mp3 is fully downloaded..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the [mp3infoutil](http://code.google.com/p/mp3infoutil/) library.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is to estimate the length of the mp3 file, based on the total file size and the loaded bytes so far:

```
//the loading progress handler
private function progressHandler(e:ProgressEvent){
   _soundLength = _sound.length*e.bytesTotal/e.bytesLoaded;
}
```

It gives a pretty good estimate. The `_soundLength` property may vary by 1 or 2 seconds until loading is complete. Anyway, it's the only way to figure out the length of any mp3. Of course, if your mp3 files have ID3 info, you can get the length of the mp3 from there, but not all mp3s do.